# ReadTimeoutError when downloading space en_core_web_lg

Tags: python, spacy

I need to download `en_core_web_lg`, so that I can load the model with spaCy. The standard command `python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg` results in a series of errors like the one below. Ultimately, the script crashes. How can I fix this?

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='objects.githubusercontent.com',
 port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")':
 /github-production-release-asset-2e65be/84940268/c9594980-c075-11ea-843f-4b84ed183bff?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20211108%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211108T170752Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=a7d448c6f74e31254967982d9d9ff620d71757bb7fcf97052c8cc26696f6f7de&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=84940268&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Den_core_web_lg-2.3.1.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github's servers appear to be having issues. [Here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/9606) is a thread on the issue tracker.

Until Github sorts things out, you can download the models from their mirrors on the HuggingFace Hub and install them with pip, though you can't do this through the `spacy download` command unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when downloading `en_core_web_trf`. It was fixed by adding `--timeout=1000` to the end of command scrip:

`python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg --timeout=1000`

Answer (score 1):

Might be the following reasons

- Your corporate network might block installing packages.
- your Mobile tethering might not have the high bandwidth.

**Solution** is

***Switch to home broadbrand and it should install seemlessly***